# QGIS error when importing .asc LIDAR data

Tags: qgis, raster, import, lidar

First let me say that I am novice in GIS department. As archaeologist I had only some courses 8 years back when i was still studying.

Now, the problem:

When I try to import .asc as raster layer I get this message:

> ngridded dataset: At line 3, X spacing was 0.000000. Expected >0 value

I know this is a problem because "Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive lines"

But my format viewed in Notepad++ is like this:

```
426000.78;55000.15;562.24 
426000.78;55001.15;562.22 
426000.78;55002.15;562.20
426000.78;55003.15;562.30
426000.78;55004.15;562.21
426000.78;55005.15;562.21
426000.78;55006.15;562.27
```

And my question - How do I change it to readable format. Any quick solutions?

Comment: Have you tried installing the LASTools Qgis plugin: For usage and installation, you can follow a tutorial : [Follow this link](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) Or the Qgis docs [and this link](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/fr/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html) And then import ur dataset using this tools
Hope that helps

Comment: I have tired this and it works on zLAS format of data. Thnks! But i would also like to know how to work with DMR in .asc format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to load the data into LibreOffice Calc, and sort the data on the second column, then the first one ascending. The result should look like:

```
426000.78;55000.15;562.24 
426001.78;55000.15;562.22 
426002.78;55000.15;562.20
426003.78;55000.15;562.30
426004.78;55000.15;562.21
426005.78;55000.15;562.21
426006.78;55000.15;562.27
....
426000.78;55001.15;562.96
426001.78;55001.15;562.22
```

Saving to csv should give you the right format for GDAL.

See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html for more details.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at the whole dataset, your grid has no constant cell size, maybe due to reprojection from another CRS.

So your only chance to use the data is to round the data to full meter cell size, or import it as delimited text point layer, then run `Raster -> Interpolation -> Interpolation` on it.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do with GDAL? DO i need to download program, which will transform csv to .asc format? How do i do this? Am noob in this field :D

Comment: GDAL works in the background of QGIS. So if your data has a format that GDAL can read, QGIS is able to dispay it.

Comment: Im really sorry but i just cant get my head around this. I have sorted data in second column (i used extended selection) and then sorted first one ascending (also used extend selection). When i open csv save in QGIS i get this Ungridded dataset: At line 2, X spacing was 0.000000. Expected >0 value

Comment: I am not sure if notepad++ can sort on two columns in one step (which I had in mind using LibreOfficeCalc). With the two sortings your result would look the same as in your question?

Comment: I did sort out both columns as you said in LibreOFfice Calc...and i get error as i posed it yesterday... im i doing something wrong?

Comment: i ee wht i nee  to do, but i just dont know how. I first select all three columns, then Data->Sort. There i select in key1 second row ascending, and under key2 first row  ascending. I tried also other possibilities, but no success.

Comment: Does it show up in Calc the way I ordered them?

Comment: No it didnt. When value in second column changes, there is a error in first column, as it doesnt starts at again as etc 426000.78, but continues ascending. This coordinates are in D48GK system.

Comment: Can you share the file via dropbox? Alternatively, you can load the data as delimited text, and run `Raster -> Interpolation -> Interpolation` on it.

Comment: here is the file https://mega.co.nz/#!ZdtmkISI!nL8ZyYXwyulWhUnhPgueWXNhE459gQdnI-O2YPc2BuU

Comment: It would work if the grid would be equally spaced, but there are rounding errors in the coordinates. You can either fix them in Calc, or round to full meters, or use delimited text for points to be interpolated.

Comment: Thnks i will do it. Thnks for all the help :D

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just ran into this same problem with the same dataset.

I just want to mention that problem here:

> UPDATE
>
> Looking at the whole dataset, your grid has no constant cell size, maybe due to > > reprojection from another CRS.

Is easily resolved by rounding all the X/Y values to the nearest decimeter.

I did this in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
read_delim("GK1_426_55.asc", delim=";", col_names=FALSE)  %>% 
  transmute(X=round(X1, 1),
            Y=round(X2, 1),
            Z=X3) %>% 
  arrange(Y, X) %>% 
  write_delim(path="GK1_426_55_fixed.asc", delim=";")
```

Afterwards GDAL/QGIS has no problem reading it. You just need to give it the CRS.